# Magento 2 default theme?

Tags: magento-2.1, theme

I am new to Magento 2, been using 1.9 before.

I installed Magento 2 with `Venustheme cricket` theme. Now when I go to `app/design/frontend` there is only `Venustheme` directory.

Does that mean that the default theme files are not there there anymore? Also, when editing the content of the `Venustheme/cricket`, I am editing the theme files and there are not magento default files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento 2 file structure is changed, you won't find core files in `app/design` or in `app/code`. In Magento 2 the core files or default theme files are located at

> your_magento2_root/vendor/magento

here you will find the folders for the core modules like for `catalog` module there is **module-catalog**. For theme you can check `theme-frontend-luma` folder. you can [check this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html) for more details.